# I need help for java.util.PriorityQueue, java.io.BufferedReader and java.io.PrintWriter to read and write to JSON file

Tags: java, json, bufferedreader, printwriter

First of all, i'm completely noob in Java... and i need help to modify a piece of code.
The current code, write data to a CSV file and i need to modify it to save to JSON format, but using java.util.PriorityQueue, java.io.BufferedReader and java.io.PrintWriter. Can anyone help me to achieve this ?
Here is the code:

```
Route.java file:
   import Exceptions.FailedCheckException;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;



public class Route implements Comparable<Route> {
    private Integer id; 
    private String name; 
    private Coordinates coordinates; 
    private java.time.ZonedDateTime creationDate; 
    private Location from; 
    private Location to; 
    private Long distance; 

    java.time.ZonedDateTime getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Route{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", coordinates=" + coordinates +
                ", creationDate=" + creationDate +
                ", from=" + from +
                ", to=" + to +
                ", distance=" + distance +
                '}';
    }


    public String toCSVfile() {
        String CSV = id + "," + name + "," + coordinates.getX() + "," + coordinates.getY() + "," + creationDate + ",";
        if (from != null)
            CSV += from.getX() + "," + from.getY() + "," + from.getZ() + "," + from.getName() + ",";
        else
            CSV += "null,,,,";
        CSV += to.getX() + "," + to.getY() + "," + to.getZ() + "," + to.getName() + ",";
        CSV += distance != null ? distance : "null";
        return CSV;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(ZonedDateTime creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public void setFrom(Location from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public void setTo(Location to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public void setDistance(Long distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }


    public static Checker<Long> distanceCheck = (Long L) -> {
        if (L == null) return null;
        else if (L > 1) return L;
        throw new FailedCheckException();
    };

    public static Checker<Integer> idCheck = (Integer I) -> {
        if (I != null && I > 0) return I;
        else throw new FailedCheckException();
    };

    public static Checker<String> nameCheck = (String S) -> {
        if (S != null && S.length() != 0) return S;
        else throw new FailedCheckException();
    };


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Route route) {
        int result = getName().compareTo(route.getName());

        if (result == 0 && getDistance() != null && route.getDistance() != null) {
            result = getDistance().compareTo(route.getDistance());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And here is the SaveManagement.java file:

```
    import Exceptions.FailedCheckException;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Class operating with files
 */

public class SaveManagement {
    private static File file;

    public static void setFile(File file) {
        SaveManagement.file = file;
    }

    /**
     * file saving in CSV format
     */
    public static void saveToFile(Collection c) {
        if (file == null)
            file = new File("save.csv");
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
            for (Route r : c.list) {
                fileWriter.write(r.toCSVfile() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File Access Error");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a collection from a saved file
     */
    @NotNull
    public static Collection listFromSave() {
        Collection collection = new Collection();
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
            String[] args;
            for (int lineNum = 1; scan.hasNext(); lineNum++) {
                try {
                    String line = scan.nextLine();
                    args = line.split(",", 14);

                    Route route = new Route();
                    int id = Route.idCheck.checker(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
                    if (collection.searchById(id) == null)
                        route.setId(id);
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid id received");
                        throw new FailedCheckException();
                    }

                    route.setName(Route.nameCheck.checker(args[1]));

                    int cx = Coordinates.xCheck.checker(Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
                    Long cy = Coordinates.yCheck.checker(Long.parseLong(args[3]));
                    route.setCoordinates(new Coordinates(cx, cy));

                    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(args[4]);
                    route.setCreationDate(dateTime);
                    if (!args[5].equals("null")) {
                        Long fromX = Location.xyzCheck.checker(Long.parseLong(args[5]));
                        Long fromY = Location.xyzCheck.checker(Long.parseLong(args[6]));
                        long fromZ = Location.xyzCheck.checker(Long.parseLong(args[7]));
                        route.setFrom(new Location(fromX, fromY, fromZ, args[8]));
                    }

                    Long toX = Location.xyzCheck.checker(Long.parseLong(args[9]));
                    Long toY = Location.xyzCheck.checker(Long.parseLong(args[10]));
                    long toZ = Location.xyzCheck.checker(Long.parseLong(args[11]));
                    route.setTo(new Location(toX, toY, toZ, args[12]));
                    if (!args[13].equals("null")) {

                        Long dis = Route.distanceCheck.checker(Long.parseLong(args[13]));
                        route.setDistance(dis);
                    }
                    collection.list.add(route);
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | DateTimeParseException | NumberFormatException | FailedCheckException e) {
                    System.out.println("\u001B[31m" + "Error reading file, line: " + "\u001B[0m" + lineNum);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("\u001B[31m" + "File Access Error" + "\u001B[0m");
        }
        Collections.sort(collection.list);
        return collection;
    }
}
```

FileWriter should be changed to PrintWriter, Scanner with BufferedReader and i don't know how to implement java.util.PriorityQueue.

Thank you!

Edit:
Should i import  java.util.PriorityQueue on Route.java  and change

> public String toCSVfile() {

to

> public String toJSONfile() {

Comment: What is the purpose of the PriorityQueue?

Comment: The developed program must satisfy the following requirements:
- For storage, you must use a collection of type java.util.PriorityQueue**
- When the application starts, the collection should be automatically populated with values ​​from the file.
- The file name must be passed to the program using: command line argument.
- Data must be stored in a json file**
- Reading data from a file must be implemented using the java.io.BufferedReader class**
- Writing data to a file must be implemented using the java.io.PrintWriter class**

I only should solve only ** ones